# Sabre Air Availability Search Throws an exception (ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED)

Tags: web-services, soap, air, wsdl, sabre

I am using Sabre SOAP Api in C#. I got the response from session creation successfully, I added wsdl Service Reference http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/tpfc/OTA_AirAvailLLS2.3.0RQ.wsdl to my test project and pass required values to parameters in the request as given in the documentation https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/Air_Availability.

this is my code to consume SOAP API

```
public OTA_AirAvailRS Method(string securitytoken, string convid, string ipcc)
        {
            try
            {

                DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
                string tstamp = dt.ToString("s") + "Z";

                //Create the message header. Provide the value for the conversation ID, the action code of the Web
                //service being called, and the value for wsse:BinarySecurityToken that was returned with
                //the SessionCreateRS message.
                //This sample calls the OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ Service, and the action code that corresponds to 
                //this service is OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ.

                MessageHeader msgHeader = new MessageHeader();
                msgHeader.ConversationId = convid;      // Put ConversationId in req header

                From from = new From();
                PartyId fromPartyId = new PartyId();
                PartyId[] fromPartyIdArr = new PartyId[1];
                fromPartyId.Value = "WebServiceClient";
                fromPartyIdArr[0] = fromPartyId;
                from.PartyId = fromPartyIdArr;
                msgHeader.From = from;

                To to = new To();
                PartyId toPartyId = new PartyId();
                PartyId[] toPartyIdArr = new PartyId[1];
                toPartyId.Value = "WebServiceSupplier";
                toPartyIdArr[0] = toPartyId;
                to.PartyId = toPartyIdArr;
                msgHeader.To = to;

                msgHeader.CPAId = ipcc;
                msgHeader.Action = "OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ";
                Service service = new Service();
                service.Value = "AirAvail";
                msgHeader.Service = service;


                MessageData msgData = new MessageData();
                msgData.MessageId = "mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com1";
                msgData.Timestamp = tstamp;
                msgHeader.MessageData = msgData;
                Security1 security = new Security1();
                security.BinarySecurityToken = securitytoken;   // Put BinarySecurityToken in req header

                //Create the request object req and the value for the IPCC in the payload of the request.

                OTA_AirAvailRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment seg = new OTA_AirAvailRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegment()
                {
                    ArrivalDateTime = "12-21T19:00",
                    DepartureDateTime = "12-21T18:00",
                    DestinationLocation = new OTA_AirAvailRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegmentDestinationLocation() { LocationCode = "DFW" },
                    OriginLocation = new OTA_AirAvailRQOriginDestinationInformationFlightSegmentOriginLocation() { LocationCode = "HNL" }
                };

                OTA_AirAvailRQ req = new OTA_AirAvailRQ();
                req.OriginDestinationInformation = new OTA_AirAvailRQOriginDestinationInformation() { FlightSegment = seg };
               // req.TimeStamp = tstamp;
               // req.OptionalQualifiers.FlightQualifiers.
                req.Version="2.3.0";

                OTA_AirAvailPortTypeClient c = new OTA_AirAvailPortTypeClient();
                OTA_AirAvailRS resp = c.OTA_AirAvailRQ(ref msgHeader, ref security, req);
                return resp;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Stack Trace : " + e.StackTrace);

            }
            return new OTA_AirAvailRS();
        }
```

its throws an exception Message: ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED

Stack:

Server stack trace:

> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.ServiceAirAvailLLSReference1.OTA_AirAvailPortType.OTA_AirAvailRQ(OTA_AirAvailRQRequest
>   request)    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.ServiceAirAvailLLSReference1.OTA_AirAvailPortTypeClient.ConsoleApplication1.ServiceAirAvailLLSReference1.OTA_AirAvailPortType.OTA_AirAvailRQ(OTA_AirAvailRQRequest
>   request) in e:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service
>   References\ServiceAirAvailLLSReference1\Reference.cs:line 7012    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.ServiceAirAvailLLSReference1.OTA_AirAvailPortTypeClient.OTA_AirAvailRQ(MessageHeader&
>   MessageHeader, Security1& Security, OTA_AirAvailRQ OTA_AirAvailRQ1) in
>   e:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service
>   References\ServiceAirAvailLLSReference1\Reference.cs:line 7020    at
>   ConsoleApplication1.SearchAirAvail.Method(String securitytoken, String
>   convid, String ipcc) in
>   e:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\SearchAirAvail.cs:line 115

Please Help Me

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the generated XML request. I suggest you to print out the exact XML request that gets sent to the server, and try using it in a Soap client like SoapUI or several others.

Pasting the request here, will also make it easier for the community to help you with your particular issue.

Comment: Agreed with MC. Posting serialized XML request and response for SOAP APIs makes troubleshooting easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer of this question..
 Just comment 
//ArrivalDateTime = "12-21T19:00"

This field is not required for request